# The entity type 'Uri' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I reference a common model, so I don't have control over the attributes in it. Assuming it looks like this:

```
  public class Message
  {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string Sender { get; set; }
      public Uri Uri { get; set; }
  }
```

Where `Uri` is `System.Uri`.

In my context I then override `OnModelCreating` in order to set the primary key:

```
  public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
          .HasKey(i => i.Id);
  }
```

I then run `Initialize` in my database initializer:

```
  public void Initialize()
  {
      _logger.Information("Ensuring database is created.");

      _messageContext.Database.Migrate();
  }
```

But get the following error:

`The entity type 'Uri' requires a primary key to be defined.`

Any hints to how I can get around this?

EDIT:

Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3062).

Comment: Does your `Uri` class has property `public Guid Id` or smth like that or a differently named property but with `[Key]` attribute? Please post `Uri` class code.

Comment: Uri is just `System.Uri`.

Comment: As far as I know, EF just doesn't support `Uri` mapping. So you have to change that to string. And if you can't - well, you will have to use some ugly workarounds.

Comment: You can't use the `Uri` type as a model property. EF is assuming it is a model of it's own which is why it's looking for a key. You should be able to use a plain string though.

Comment: Yes that's true, here is an issue about this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3062. Closed as "won't fix", so don't expect it to work any time soon.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.

Comment: Not really, just use a string.

Comment: @Evk: Well there's a "fix it yourself" solution: [Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) (from EF Core 2.1 and upwards though, still in preview)

Comment: @Tseng I see the day when EF Core will actually be usable finally coming with that 2.1 version. Especially `GroupBy` queries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entities can only contain two sorts of property types (that can be used by EF):

1. Types that map to primitive SQL types (string, int, bool, ...).
2. Types of entities defined in EF.

Since `Uri` does not map to a primitive SQL type, EF tries to handle it as if it were an entity.

Entities are stored in a separate table. To store an entity in a table, it needs a unique id.

---

There are ways around this. The method I'm suggesting maintains the `Uri` but prevents EF from trying to use it.

**Step 1 - Make the Uri [NotMapped]**

This makes it so that EF *ignores* the Uri property, since it can't properly handle it.

```
[NotMapped]
public Uri Uri { get; set; }
```

**Step 2 - Make a string property that EF *should* handle instead of the Uri.**

The string value is derived from the (now hidden) `Uri` property, but EF doesn't see that. It only sees a usable string property.

```
public String URL 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Uri = new Uri(value);
    }
 }
```

And that should do the trick. In code, you work with the `Uri` property directly (like you were already doing), but you've set up your entity so EF works with the `URL` string property instead.
After EF retrieves the entity and sets its properties (including the `URL` string property), the `Uri` property is implicitly also created and you can keep working with it.

Answer (score 3):

For EF Core 2.0 and older, @Flater's answer is correct.

For EF Core 2.1 there's more elegant and generic ways to solve that w/o polluting the model with conversion code: [Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

In your case:

```
public class UriConverter : ValueConverter<Uri, string>
{
    public static UriConverter Instance = new UriConverter();

    private UriConverter() : base(value => ToUriString(value), value => ToUri(value)) { }

    private static string ToUriString (Uri uri) => uri?.ToString();

    private static Uri ToUri(string url) => Uri.TryPrase(url, out Uri uri)?uri:null;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(e => e.Uri)
        .HasConversion(UriConverter.Instance);
}
```

Or for this very simple case w/o a helper class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(e => e.Uri)
        .HasConversion(
            uri => uri?.ToString(),
            url => Uri.TryPrase(url, out Uri uri)?uri:null
        );
}
```